# Analyzing strings in Python

Tags: python, string, input

I'd like to make a program in python that analyzes a users input.

For example if the user writes "Hello, I'm 19 years old", the program can see that 
the string has numbers in it and assigns "19" to a variable.

It could also at the same time see that the string has the word "years" in it and makes the variable:

```
years = 19
```

I'm pretty new to python and programming in general, so sorry if the question is weird.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try any google-fu? how about *"Python read user input"*, *"Python count letters in a string"*?

Comment: looks like homework, what have you tried?

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the length of the string using function [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len). `str` can contain all chars and letters. Try the following code:

```
word = input("Waiting for input: ")
print("Found "+str(len(word))+" letters!")
```

Testing it:

```
Waiting for input: hello
Found 5 letters!
```

Testing it with numbers and other chars:

```
Waiting for input: hello123!@#
Found 11 letters!
```

Comment: thats pretty handy but i'd like it to also be able to analyze different characters and numbers in the input string .. kind of hard to explain

Comment: @kanuki Have you seen the edit? It will also work with different chars and numbers.